# How to config nginx as proxy server for nodejs pod using Openshift?

Tags: nginx, openshift, openshift-3

I am familiar with running nginx as proxy server but I am having hard time to put things together using openshift. I have nodejs app and want to use using nginx as proxy server. This is my nginx conf file. Should I replace `server_name` with service? is there other way to achieve this in openshift?

```
upstream myapp {
    server 127.0.0.1:8080;
    keepalive 8;
}

# the nginx server instance
server {
    listen 0.0.0.0:80;
    server_name x.x.x.x;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/my-app.com.log;

    location / {
      autoindex on;
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
      proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;

      proxy_pass http://myapp/;
      proxy_redirect off;
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your guess is correct, you need to refer to the service by its name. If the service  isn't in the default namespace you need to use the Fully Qualified Domain Name:

```
<svc-name>.<namespace>.svc.cluster.local
```

Instead of hardcoding this configuration into the container, the proper way is to apply it as a configmap to the cluster and mount it as a volume into the specified path for nginx pod.

Comment: in my case I am not seeing cluster.local. All I see service name is as `<svc-name>.<namespace>.svc`

Comment: I am not sure where are you looking for the cluster.local? Please see the following documentation: https://docs.openshift.com/enterprise/3.0/architecture/additional_concepts/networking.html

When you create a pod you have to specify a namespace (same for the service) if you don't specify a namespace it picks the currently active namespace (usually default). Let's say that you named the nodejs service `nodejs` and you didn't specify any namespace (resolving into the default ns) this means that the FQDN for your service is `nodejs.default.svc.cluster.local`. Give it a try ;)

Comment: just confirming - nodejs.default.svc.cluster.local will go in upstream block? `upstream myapp {
    server nodejs.default.svc.cluster.local:8080;
    keepalive 8;
}`

Comment: Are these containers both started within one pod? or are they in separate pods?

Comment: do you have a service for your app and what is it named?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200250/discussion-between-rinormaloku-and-user557657).

Comment: `NAME                   TYPE        CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)    AGE
nginx-custom           ClusterIP   172.0.x.x   <none>        80/TCP     4m
s2i-nodejs-container   ClusterIP   172.0.x.x   <none>        8080/TCP   1d`